# Taylor expansion of quotient

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Let $f,g$ be two functions defined on an intervalle $I$. The Taylor expansion of f and g in $x_{0} \in I$ is respectively given by:
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_{i}(x−x_{0})^{i}+o((x−x_{0})^{k})$$
and
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_{i}(x−x_{0})^{i}+o((x−x_{0})^{k})$$
My suggestion is i would like to make a Taylor expansion of the quotient $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=A_{r}(x−x_{0})+o((x−x_{0})^{r})$ where r is an integer and $A_{r}$ is a function depending on $x-x_{0}$. Take for instance $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ and $g(x)=cos(x)$ and x0=0. I have an other question: for n goes to $+ \infty$ and $s \in Z^{+}$, can we say that $o(n^{−s})$ is identical to $o((n+1)^{−s})$?

Comment: Simply note that $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^xx^i$$ hence $$\frac1{g(x_0)+h}=\frac1{g(x_0)}\frac1{1+\frac1{g(x_0)}h}=\sum_{i=0}^x\left(-\frac1{g(x_0)}h\right)^i$$ where $h$ is the nonconstant terms in your taylor expansion of $g$. 

The only issue really is when $g(x_0)=0$ and in that case it only works if the root of $f$ at $x_0$ has a degree at least $g(x_0)$ else your quotient does not exist.

Comment: and yes $o(n^{-s})=o((n+1)^{-s})$